# iOS 8: Beta Testing with TestFlight: None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices:

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to follow the steps here for iOS 8: Beta Testing with TestFlight: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224

It was mentioned that I don't need to add the devices for my tester and no longer needed to generate provisioning profile.

> For example, it's no longer necessary to juggle device identifiers and provisioning profiles. To test an application with TestFlight there's no need to add the devices of your testers and it's no longer necessary to 
>   generate a provisioning profile for ad hoc distribution.

However, when I try to archive my app, I am getting error

> None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices:
>   Testing iPhone 6+.  Xcode can resolve this issue by downloading a new provisioning profile from the Member Center.

Comment: TestFlight is going to close down soon. I think you shouldn't take their guide too seriously.

Comment: @Shang This is about iTunesConnect TestFlight, not TestFlightApp. Did you even open the link?

Answer (score 0):

Use a distribution provisioning profile and a production certificate to upload the binary instead of a development profile and certificate. It will work.